# Error:Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]:

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my app i entered the value of Amount field into textfield and the datatype of that field is float and then insert it into database.when i run my app it gives following error.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:   '-[NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]:
```

here is my code to insert data:

```
 NSString *amt=txtTotalBill.text;
float amount = [amt floatValue];


NSString *insertData=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into tbl_Bills(Amount) values ('%f')",amount];
```

and the app gives error at this point:

```
  [label3 setText:[[BillTableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Amount"]];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The object returned by `[[BillTableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Amount"]` is not a `NSString`.

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[BillTableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Amount"]];

[label3 setText:string];
```

Comment: wow, that really worked!! :) but why does actually happens?? why don't it itself convert to string??

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but the object return is a `NSNumber`. Thus cant be placed directly in the `text` property of the `UILabel`. As you can see in my example if create a `NSString` using the description of the `NSNumber`. You could also use `NSNumberFormatter`.

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to set `Number` as label's text. Where label text `must` be a string. So you need to first convert `Number` value into `NSString`...